# Can I use the terminal from 11.04 in 10.10?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I had Ubuntu 10.10.

I had seen terminal of Ubuntu 11 version.

It's really good to see the maximize features of that terminal.

Can i upgrade my current terminal to Version 11 terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you probably refer to as "maximize features of the terminal" is the look of [Unity](http://unity.ubuntu.com/), the standard desktop of Ubuntu starting version 11.

The closer you can get to this when using the GNOME terminal in earlier versions of Ubuntu is:

- either by clicking the [maximize button](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_desktop_guides/gnome_2.14_user_guide/overview-windows.html) on the terminal window decorations,
- or by selecting the *Full screen* menu item from the *View* menu.